# Springboot Integration test: Update application.yml property with pwd before bean initialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have writing Springboot Integration test. There is an application.yml in src/test/resources.
There is a property in the yml:

`testFilePath: "projectBaseDirectoryPathVariable/src/test/resources/testFiles"`

A bean, used in the test, has to read this value "testFilePath", in the bean (class) constructor.

Right before executing integration tests, I want to be able to replace the value of `projectBaseDirectoryPathVariable` with the user directory (or PWD path). So that, the bean initialization has the correct full path, i.e `/users/usrname/projects/project_name/src/test/resources/testFiles`

I tried using **BeforeAll() method**, which would replace application.yml file contents, and hence replace projectBaseDirectoryPathVariable with the full path. But the bean (class) is using the older value "projectBaseDirectoryPathVariable" only while calling its constructor.

What could be a way to handle this case?

This is the test:

```
@Slf4j
@ActiveProfiles({"test", "master"})
@SpringBootTest
public class MyIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    ClassUsingApplicationYml classUsingApplicationYml;

    @BeforeAll
    static void beforeAll() throws IOException {
        //Some code
    }

    @Test
    void dummyClassTest() {
        // Some code
    }
}
```

ClassUsingApplicationYml/bean.

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class ClassUsingApplicationYml implements Tasklet {

    public ClassUsingApplicationYml(@Value("${file.results}") String resultsDirectory) {
        //resultsDirectory should get "/users/usrname/projects/project_name/src/test/resources/testFiles", 
        //but it is getting "projectBaseDirectoryPathVariable/src/test/resources/testFiles"
        this.resultsDirectory = resultsDirectory;
    }

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws IOException {
        //Some code
        log.info(resultsDirectory);
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
file
 results: "projectBaseDirectoryPathVariable/src/test/resources/testFiles"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can slightly hack it.

```
file
   property : projectBaseDirectoryPathVariable 
   results: ${file.property}/src/test/resources/testFiles
```

And now start your test with an environment variable `FILE_PROPERTY` that you want to override it with. That can be done in `@BeforeAll` via `System.setEnv(...)` and cleared after in `@AfterAll` with `System.clearProperty`

Comment: How do I access the value of file.property from application.yml in the Integration test?

Comment: I'm not able to access file.property in the Integration test. Can someone please help?